# Fit Div to page?

Tags: html, image, hover, scale

I'm trying to make hover images and add a link to the div but the div does not fit to page.

For example:
http://test.peterstavrou.com/

See how the image gets cut off?

Anyone have any ideas?

Below is my code.

**CSS**

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.peterstavrou.com/product/ebay-listing-template/"><div id="cf"><img class="bottom" src="http://www.peterstavrou.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/eBay-Listing-Template-Price.jpg" alt="eBay Template Listing" width="292" height="311" /><img class="top" src="http://www.peterstavrou.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/eBay-Listing-Template.jpg" alt="eBay Template Listing" width="292" height="311" /></div></a>

&nbsp;
<strong>Summary:</strong> TEST TEST TEST
<a title="eBay Template Listing" href="http://www.peterstavrou.com/product/ebay-listening-template/">Click here for more information.</a>
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hz80govj/

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "fit to page"? As in, filling up 100% of the viewport?

Comment: Please see  http://test.peterstavrou.com/ for example
See how the image gets cut off?

Answer (score 0):

the div only contains an image, so it's width/height is derived from that image width/height, which is currently set to `width="292" height="311"`.

If you want the div/image to adjust to screen size, remove the width/height from the image and set image size using css:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not at all clear, But as I understood you need to fit the div to the size of the picture. If I am correct use the following CSS.

```
#cf {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
}

.bottom {
    position:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Please see  http://test.peterstavrou.com/ for example
See how the image gets cut off?

Comment: If you can add inline code just do it, even if it is not a good method. Add change
`<img class="bottom" id="NewId" src="http://www.peterstavrou.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/eBay-Listing-Template-Price.jpg" alt="eBay Template Listing" width="292" height="311"">`

into 

`<img class="bottom" id="NewId" src="http://www.peterstavrou.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/eBay-Listing-Template-Price.jpg" alt="eBay Template Listing" width="292" height="311" style="
    position: inherit;
">`

Comment: Adding style=" position: inherit; "> works, but then I cannot add a link to the div if that is applied. When I do it removes the hover effect. For example: http://test.peterstavrou.com/test/